# Open a link in a different browser tab

Tags: javascript, php

How do I open the link in a different browser tab?

Here's the snippet I've got:

```
        $URL='../uploads/'.$wec;
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.location.href='{$URL}';</script>";    
        echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content="0;URL=' . $URL . '">';
```

I'm aware that `target="_bank"` would push the link in a different tab, but not sure how to embed to the snippet I have.

tried this but doesn't seems to be working.

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript', target='_blank'>document.location.href='{$URL}';</script>";
```

Comment: Don't use `document.location.href` use [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open). Also keep in mind that opening a new window will trigger the popup protection of browsers in most cases.

Comment: @apokryfos what bothers me wih window.open() could be the pop up blockers. Is there a workaround to the document.location.href?

Comment: try `windows.open(url, '_blank')` but you can never have a guarantee it will open in a new tab, it depends on the client

Comment: The `location` object holds information about the location of the current window/tab so you can't use it to manipulate or create another window/tab.